# Single row inline form elements distribute across 3 rows when viewed on mobile device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following markup, using bootstrap. 
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11339/

I have an inline form to the right which sits nicely in one row when viewed on a desktop.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="panel panel-default borderless-panel db-panel">
               <div class="panel-body db-panel-body">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <a href="app-add-campaign.html" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">Add New</a>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" value="14 March, 2013" id="datepicker-01">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="14 March, 2013" id="datepicker-01">
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="fui-calendar"></span><span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Yesterday</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Last Week</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Last Month</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Custom Date</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                   </div></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

However, my form distributes itself over 3 rows when I view it on a mobile device.

[image]
 I want it to be placed below the Add New button, but in one single row taking up the entire width. Please could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 10px;
}
#myForm .group-change {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #myForm .btn.btn-embossed {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #myForm input,
  #myForm .dropdown-toggle {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default borderless-panel db-panel">
    <div class="panel-body db-panel-body">
      <form id="myForm" class="form-inline" role="form"> <a href="app-add-campaign.html" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">Add New Campaign</a>

        <div class="group-change">
          <input type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" value="14 March, 2013" id="datepicker-01">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="14 March, 2013" id="datepicker-01"> <span class="input-group-btn" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button"><span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">Today</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Yesterday</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Last Week</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Last Month</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Custom Date</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```